# EditText with a hint on multiple lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a large `EditText` box.  I want a hint in the box to look like this (syntax highlight not intended):

```
Hint about the first line
Hint about the second line
Hint about the third line
```

I tried using `android:hint="@string/hints"` on the `EditText` with the following in strings.xml, but the hint was still on a single line.

```
<string name="hints">
Hint about the first line
Hint about the second line
Hint about the third line
</string>
```

How can one obtain a multiline hint in an `EditText`?

Comment: I found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060772/set-multi-line-for-edittexts-hint/34773607#34773607

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can include newlines in strings by explicitly specifying them:

```
<string name="hint">Manny, Moe and Jack\nThey know what I\'m after.</string>
```

Newlines in the XML are treated as spaces.

Comment: I Tried same **\n** for Hint new line,it's work at design time i mean in XML ,but it didn't work in real device in real device its display single line.can explain what the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate string resource for each line:

```
<string name="hint_one">Hint about the first line</string>
<string name="hint_two">Hint about the second line</string>
<string name="hint_three">Hint about the third line</string>
```

don't include an `android:hint` attribute in your layout XML.  Where the `EditText` is created, set the hint manually:

```
// get the string values
final Resources res = getResources();
final String one   = res.getString(R.string.hint_one);
final String two   = res.getString(R.string.hint_two);
final String three = res.getString(R.string.hint_three);

// set the hint
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.some_edit_text);
et.setHint( one + "\n" + two + "\n" + three );
```