# Set multi-line for EditText's HINT

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I know that I could change the No. of lines for EditeText's Text, yet could I change that of EditText's hint as well?

I could not find a solution online.

Thanks for the help.

My Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.property_search, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    final MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
    int searchSrcTextId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(searchSrcTextId);
    searchEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
   searchEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    searchEditText.setHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
}
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="search_hint">keyword, location, \nmax price (e.g. 1K, 1M)</string>
```

What I want is:

keyword, location,

max price (e.g. 1K, 1M)

Comment: post some code and images of desired and current results..

Comment: r u getting any error?

Comment: No, there is no error. But only the words 'keyword, location, ..." is shown. 
What I want (at the end ofmy code above):   
"keyword, location,  ----------NEW LINE------------
max price (e.g. 1K, 1M)"

Answer (score 15):

Nothing worked for me but:

```
 <EditText
         android:id="@+id/text"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
         android:hint="\n"/>
```

To be honest I don´t understand why.. but including "\n" as hint in the xml did the trick!

Now you can call setHint from Java code:

```
searchEditText.setHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
```

and remove the \n from strings.xml if you want to allow the text split automatically according to the room

```
<string name="search_hint">keyword, location, max price (e.g. 1K, 1M)</string>
```

Comment: this should be the marked answer .. I still don't know the reason, but it's working

Answer (score 9):

use new line separator \n in ur hint.

like

```
android:hint="first line of hint \n second line of hint so on.."
```

in strings

```
<string name="urhint">first line of hint \n second line of hint so on..</string>

android:hint="@string/urhint"
```

hope it works..

Comment: make sure that u r setting ur edittext height to wrapcontent...n pls post ur xml too

Answer (score 7):

unbelievable but true: setting the long text programmatically instead of setting it in the xml did the trick.

```
<TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
```

Set the text programmatically:

```
mEditTextRemark.setHint(R.string...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

String.xml

```
<string name="hint">Hint first line \n Hint second line \n Hint third line</string>
```

Layout.xml

```
 <EditText
         android:id="@+id/emailText"   
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/login_edittext_background"
         android:imeOptions="actionNext"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:hint="@string/hint"/>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. 
Is it because I am changing the actionBar's searchView, which is limited to a specific height?
I set those variables dynamically by, 
1. searchEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
2. searchEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

Answer (score -1):

set below two lines in your edittext in your xml file

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:lines="3"
```

so gives 3 multilines box are display in preview